# Not able to click on a button,which is inside an iframe in chrome browser using webdriver

Tags: ruby, google-chrome, selenium, watir-webdriver

[image]

In the above HTML page, I could click on 'Choose file' button in Internet explorer using

@browser.frame(:name, 'fileUI').file_field(:name, 'isoFile').set(path)

When I try to use the same code for chrome browser it is not working and getting following error:
[image]
Any way that I click on this button?

Comment: Which error you are getting?

Comment: I don't know about ruby bindings, but this link might help you in switching to frame and then interacting with the element: [https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/RubyBindings](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/RubyBindings)

Comment: @Helping Hands- Have pasted the error message which says UnknownFrameException

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Watir-Webdriver v0.6.5, a change was made to how locating frames worked:

- Before (ie pre-0.6.5), `browser.frame` located frame and iframe elements.
- Now, `browser.frame` locates frame elements and `browser.iframe` locates iframe elements.

Since you are dealing with an iframe, you will need to use the `iframe` instead of `frame` method:

```
@browser.iframe(:name, 'fileUI').file_field(:name, 'isoFile').set(path)
```

The reason that this worked with Internet Explorer is likely due to the use of the Watir metagem. The Watir gem will load Watir-Classic when using IE and Watir-Webdriver when using other browsers. The change to the `frame` method was only made in Watir-Webdriver, it has not yet been changed in Watir-Classic.